# Rename PouchDB without rebuilding indices

Tags: indexing, backup, rename, indexeddb, pouchdb

We are currently doing an architectural change that requires the local [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) to be renamed. As some of the databases are quite big and the indices take quite long to build, it would be great to instead just rename or copy the data as well as the indices from an existing local PouchDB.
PouchDB creates one *main* IndexedDB (`_pouch_<db name>`) that holds all data and then it creates further IndexedDBs (`_pouch_<db name>-mrview-<some hash>`) that hold the created indices. The names of these DBs can be found in two [local docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/local-documents.html): `_local/_pouch_dependentDbs` and `_local/mrviews`.

My ideas so far were:

- Use this [IndexedDB backup script](https://gist.github.com/loilo/ed43739361ec718129a15ae5d531095b) which does a JSON backup of the whole IndexedDB and also allows to write a JSON string into a IndexedDB. This script did not work however, maybe due to the complex `keyPath` values. I am not an expert with IndexedDBs so I can't say for sure.
- Sync the old PouchDB to a new PouchDB with the new name and destroy the old one afterwards. This works fine but leaves the problem that the indices have to be re-created (which I want to avoid).
- Fetch the `_local/_pouch_dependentDbs` and `_local/mrviews` objects and use this information to also sync the DBs used for the map-reduce-views (`_pouch_<dbname>-mrview-<some hash>`) to new DBs with the new name and then also update the `_local/...` docs and write them to the new database. The process works but the indices still have to be built afterwards. This is probably because the contents of the `by-sequence` and `local-store` stores are not synchronized but I could also not find more information on the contents of these stores.

I was wondering if anyone here knows a good solution that makes this whole process easier (as its just about renaming a DB).

Comment: Is it not possible to build up the renamed db while the user interacts with the old db, then swap and delete and some point? It is a complex approach but can be done I think.  That doesn't suit your requirement but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: It's a interesting option, thanks for mentioning. So far I can only think of the problem: what if the user kills the session before the indexing is done and the databases are swapped?

Comment: Don't swap db's until indexes are built?